# How to set the width of each cell in a row as a ratio of the overall table width?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following table needs to be processed by the appended code. The issues I have are

1. How to set the width of the three cells in the first row to be 20, 70, and 10% in order since `.PreferredWidth` property doesn't change the output to be what I want?
2. The widths of `.Cell(1,1)` and `.Cell(2,1)` seem to be linked to each other, which prevents me from setting a different width for each one of them.

So, how to fix the code to address the previous issues?

[image]

```
Sub LoopOverTablesAndTransform()
    
    Dim StartPage, EndPage, SearchRange, CellsRange As Range
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, t As Long
    Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    With wdDoc
        
        Set StartPage = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:=130)
        Set EndPage = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:=133)
        EndPage.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End
        Set SearchRange = .Range(Start:=StartPage.Start, End:=EndPage.End)
        
        With SearchRange
        
            For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
            
                'Debug.Print .Tables(t).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            
                With .Tables(t).Range.Find
            
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Format = False
                    .Text = "<[OBASRMCHUIVELNG]{3}[1-4][1-9]{2}>"
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .MatchCase = True
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .Execute
                
                    If .Found = True _
                       And SearchRange.Tables(t).Rows.Count = 11 _
                       And SearchRange.Tables(t).Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15189684 Then
                        
                        With SearchRange.Tables(t)
                        
                            .AllowAutoFit = False
                            .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
                            .Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
                                   
                            .Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
                            
                            .Cell(1, 1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
                            .Cell(1, 1).PreferredWidth = 20
                            .Cell(1, 2).PreferredWidth = 70

                            .Cell(2, 1).PreferredWidth = 30       
                            .Cell(2, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15132390
                            .Cell(2, 1).Range.Font.Bold = True
                                    
                            .Rows(3).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15132390
                            .Rows(3).Range.Font.Bold = True
                            .Rows(3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                                    
                            .Rows(4).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15132390
                            .Rows(4).Range.Font.Bold = True
                            .Rows(4).Cells.DistributeWidth
                                    
                            .Rows(5).Cells.DistributeWidth
                            
                            Set CellsRange = ActiveDocument.Range( _
                            Start:=.Cell(6, 1).Range.Start, End:=.Cell(6, 4).Range.End)
                            
                            CellsRange.Cells.PreferredWidth = 100 / 4

                            .Cell(6, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15132390
                            .Cell(6, 1).Range.Font.Bold = True
                            .Cell(6, 3).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15132390
                            .Cell(6, 3).Range.Font.Bold = True
                                    
                            .Rows(7).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15132390
                            .Rows(7).Range.Font.Bold = True
                            .Rows(7).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                                    
                            .Cell(8, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
                                    
                            .Rows(9).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15132390
                            .Rows(9).Range.Font.Bold = True
                            .Rows(9).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                                    
                            .Rows(10).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15132390
                            .Rows(10).Range.Font.Bold = True
                            .Rows(10).Cells.DistributeWidth
                                    
                            .Rows(11).Cells.DistributeWidth
                                    
                            .Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                            .Borders.InsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth100pt
                            .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                            .Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth100pt
                                    
                            .Range.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                        
                        End With
                    
                    End If
                
                End With
            
            Next
        
        End With
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your first step should be to find out if you can do what you want by using the UI. If you can’t, you won’t be able to do it in code either.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub TblDemo()
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
  .PreferredWidth = 100
  .Cell(2, 1).Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdColumnBreak
  .Cell(1, 1).PreferredWidth = 70
  .Cell(1, 2).PreferredWidth = 20
  .Cell(1, 3).PreferredWidth = 10
  .Range.Characters.Last.Next.Delete
End With
End Sub
```

The code works by first splitting the table, then formatting the 1st row, after which the split is removed.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could explain a bit more what `.Cell(2, 1).Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdColumnBreak` and `.Range.Characters.Last.Next.Delete` actually do.

Comment: I'd have thought it fairly obvious those two lines split the table (which inserts an empty paragraph after the split), then rejoin the table (by removing the same empty paragraph), respectively. You would see that if you stepped through the code.